# HP ZR2740W - no display, cause identified, how to fix it?

Tags: external-display, lcd, connector, blank-screen

One day on this monitor picture went black and did not come back until I disassembled it and simply reseated the LVDS (??? I know Laptops have LVDS ribbon, is this cable the same sans form?) cable - that is the one that leads from control board to the actual LCD matrix. Unfortunately the display keeps to go out on this monitor in regular intervals. So I'm opening it and reseat the cable and then picture is back for several days. And then out.

Since I did that several times already it seems that the connector slips by fraction of a milimeter when monitor is being adjusted etc. ANy way to fix it place that is fast and easy (can't afford replacing right now)?

Interestingly this is one of two monitors I use right now, and second one works flawlessly third year now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just that very flat foil cable working loose from the connector the fix is very simple:
Put a little strip of adhesive tape (scotch tape or similar) partially on the connector and partially on the foil cable. That should provide enough friction/resistance to keep the cable in place and it will not interfere with the electronics.

It s a quite common problem with these connectors: They don't really grip the cable all that well.
In fact: I've seen quite a lot of laptops (HP, Lenovo and Toshiba's) where tape is used as standard out of the factory for foil cables to the LCD or to the internal keyboard/mousepad.

Comment: Laptops are easy (worked as a Dell CSE), this is about external 27" monitor... The cable and connector are yuuuuge.

Comment: Ended up having used masking tape (painter type, yellow from paper) to hold the connector and cable in place. Second month without issues.

Comment: @AcePL Glad to hear that :-)